# Анимация круга SVG

Tags: svg

не подскажите как реализовать такую анимацию круга только на SVG
https://codepen.io/HTMLProgrammer/pen/qBbdJZW?editors=1010

```js
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
 w = canvas.width,
 h = canvas.height,
 angle = 0;

function draw() {
 ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
 ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

 ctx.save();
 ctx.translate(w / 2, h / 2);

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(0, 0, 50, 0, angle);

 ctx.lineTo(0, 0);

 ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
 ctx.fill();

 ctx.restore();

 if (angle < Math.PI * 2) angle += 0.1;

 requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

draw();

canvas.onclick = () => (angle = 0);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Маленький хак

```html
<svg viewBox="-250 -150 500 500" width="300px">
  <circle r="50" 
          fill="none"
          stroke="#000" 
          stroke-width="100">
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
             begin="0s" 
             dur="2s"
             values="0 315; 315 315"
             repeatCount="3"/>
  </circle>
</svg>
```

Запуск по клику на кнопке

```html
<svg viewBox="-250 -150 500 500" width="300px">
  <defs>
    <style>
      #button{
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <circle r="50" 
          fill="none"
          stroke="#000" 
          stroke-width="100">
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
             begin="button.click" 
             dur="2s"
             values="0 315; 315 315"
             repeatCount="1"/>
  </circle>
  <g id="button">
  <rect width="240" height="60" x="-120" y="150" ry="6"/>
   <text fill="white" y="185" x="-95"> Начать анимацию</text> 
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Если нужны повторы, без длинных пауз, то при радиусе равном `50` длина окружности равна `314` поэтому можно написать  `values="0, 314; 314, 0 "`

Comment: @Alexandr_TT я знаю - от фанаря писал размеры

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 4):

```js
// Только для того, чтобы получить stroke-dasharray

const circle = document.querySelector('svg circle');
const circleLength = circle.getTotalLength();

console.log(circleLength);
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

svg {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 display: block;
}

svg circle {
 stroke-width: 20;
 stroke: #000;
 fill: none;
 stroke-dasharray: 63;
 stroke-dashoffset: 63;
 transition: stroke-dashoffset linear 2s;
}

svg:hover circle {
 stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="10"/>
</svg>
```